# Can you determine where a pillager captain spawns in a pillager outpost?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

AFAIK they spawn on the top level of a pillager outpost all the time (not 100% sure). But is there maybe a single spot where he "respawns"? This doesn't seem to be tackled in any of the wikis.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pillager_Outpost#Mobs):

> Both regular pillagers and **pillager captains** can continuously spawn around the structure.
> In Bedrock Edition, they spawn at or below a particular location in the outpost; specifically, they choose the northwest corner of the highest opaque block with a non-solid block on top.